# how to call a method in setter through reflection C#

Tags: c#

I am dynamically creating a class which inherits ViewModelBase of MvvmLight.
In the class the properties should implement that INotifyPropertyChanged interface method RaiseEvent.

This is the complete code

```
// Our intermediate language generator
ILGenerator ilgen;

// The assembly builder
AssemblyBuilder asmBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("PeopleLibrary"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

// The module builder
ModuleBuilder modBuilder = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("PeopleLibrary", "PeopleLibrary.dll");

// The person class builder
TypeBuilder personBuilder = modBuilder.DefineType("PeopleLibrary.Person", TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(ViewModelBase));

// The default constructor
ConstructorBuilder ctorBuilder = personBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);

// Two fields: m_firstname, m_lastname
FieldBuilder fBuilderFirstName = personBuilder.DefineField("firstname", typeof(string), FieldAttributes.Private);
FieldBuilder fBuilderLastName = personBuilder.DefineField("lastname", typeof(string), FieldAttributes.Private);

// Two properties for this object: FirstName, LastName
PropertyBuilder pBuilderFirstName = personBuilder.DefineProperty("FirstName", System.Reflection.PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, typeof(string), null);
PropertyBuilder pBuilderLastName = personBuilder.DefineProperty("LastName", System.Reflection.PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, typeof(string), null);

// Custom attributes for get, set accessors
MethodAttributes getSetAttr = MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.SpecialName;

// get,set accessors for FirstName
MethodBuilder mGetFirstNameBuilder = personBuilder.DefineMethod("get_FirstName", getSetAttr, typeof(string), Type.EmptyTypes);

// Code generation
ilgen = mGetFirstNameBuilder.GetILGenerator();
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fBuilderFirstName); // returning the firstname field
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

MethodBuilder mSetFirstNameBuilder = personBuilder.DefineMethod("set_FirstName", getSetAttr, null, new Type[] { typeof(string) });

// Code generation
ilgen = mSetFirstNameBuilder.GetILGenerator();
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fBuilderFirstName); // setting the firstname field from the first argument (1)
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

// get,set accessors for LastName
MethodBuilder mGetLastNameBuilder = personBuilder.DefineMethod("get_LastName", getSetAttr, typeof(string), Type.EmptyTypes);

// Code generation
ilgen = mGetLastNameBuilder.GetILGenerator();
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fBuilderLastName); // returning the firstname field
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

MethodBuilder mSetLastNameBuilder = personBuilder.DefineMethod("set_LastName", getSetAttr, null, new Type[] { typeof(string) });

// Code generation
ilgen = mSetLastNameBuilder.GetILGenerator();
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fBuilderLastName); // setting the firstname field from the first argument (1)
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

// Assigning get/set accessors
pBuilderFirstName.SetGetMethod(mGetFirstNameBuilder);
pBuilderFirstName.SetSetMethod(mSetFirstNameBuilder);

pBuilderLastName.SetGetMethod(mGetLastNameBuilder);
pBuilderLastName.SetSetMethod(mSetLastNameBuilder);

// Now, a custom method named GetFullName that concatenates FirstName and LastName properties
MethodBuilder mGetFullNameBuilder = personBuilder.DefineMethod("GetFullName", MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(string), Type.EmptyTypes);

// Code generation
ilgen = mGetFullNameBuilder.GetILGenerator();
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, mGetFirstNameBuilder); // getting the firstname
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, " "); // an space
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, mGetLastNameBuilder); // getting the lastname

// We need the 'Concat' method from string type
MethodInfo concatMethod = typeof(String).GetMethod("Concat", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string) });

ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, concatMethod); // calling concat and returning the result
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

// Another constructor that initializes firstname and lastname
ConstructorBuilder ctorBuilder2 = personBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard, new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });
ctorBuilder2.DefineParameter(1, ParameterAttributes.None, "firstname");
ctorBuilder2.DefineParameter(2, ParameterAttributes.None, "lastname");

// Code generation
ilgen = ctorBuilder2.GetILGenerator();

// First of all, we need to call the base constructor,
// the Object's constructor in this sample
Type objType = Type.GetType("System.Object");
ConstructorInfo objCtor = objType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);

ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, objCtor); // calling the Object's constructor

ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, mSetFirstNameBuilder); // setting the firstname field from the first argument (1)
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, mSetLastNameBuilder);  // setting the lastname field from the second argument (2)
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

// Finally, create the type and save the assembly
var type = personBuilder.CreateType();

asmBuilder.Save("PeopleLibrary.dll");
```

In that while creating properties in setter i need to do this

```
public string StudentName
{
    get
    {
        return this.studentName;
    }

    set
    {
        this.Set(() => this.StudentName, ref this.studentName, value);
    }
}
```

But now as per the code sample i found its coming like this in reflection.

```
private string firstname;

public string FirstName
{
  get
  {
    return this.firstname;
  }
  set
  {
    this.firstname = obj0;
  }
}
```

My requirement is i need to call the base class method Set in the setter as i shown. I modified the code and inherited the base class in reflection. But i am not able to this setter stuff.

Please help me. Thanks in advance !

Comment: If you're asking help with code, you need to post that code.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Sorry for that. Now i updated with code.

Comment: The problem here is that you have complex code in the setter. If you want to truly mimic the handwritten code and how the compiler generates that you need to emit an expression (or an anonymous class with the method, wrapped in a delegate), a ref parameter, etc. My best advice would be to decompile the code that you want to get, and emit the same IL instructions. In other words, decompile the first example to find all the IL instructions you need.

Comment: How is the `Set` method declared?

Comment: Thats good idea. I will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little trick for such problems. Download [this](https://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ReflectionEmitLanguage&referringTitle=Home) add-in for Reflector.

I've just compiled the following little sample:

```
    private string studentName;
    public string StudentName
    {
        get { return this.studentName; }
        set { this.Set(() => this.StudentName, ref this.studentName, value); }
    }

    private void Set(Func<string> func, ref string s, string value)
    {           
    }
```

And viewing the property setter in `Reflector` with the `Reflection.Emit` language:

```
public MethodBuilder BuildMethodset_StudentName(TypeBuilder type)
{
    // Declaring method builder
    MethodBuilder method = type.DefineMethod("set_StudentName");
    // Preparing Reflection instances
    MethodInfo method1 = typeof(Program).GetMethod(
        "<set_StudentName>b__0", 
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, 
        null, 
        new Type[]{
            }, 
        null
        );
    ConstructorInfo ctor2 = typeof(System.Func<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(String)).GetConstructor(
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, 
        null, 
        new Type[]{
            typeof(Object),
            typeof(IntPtr)
            }, 
        null
        );
    FieldInfo field3 = typeof(Program).GetField("studentName", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    MethodInfo method4 = typeof(Program).GetMethod(
        "Set", 
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, 
        null, 
        new Type[]{
            typeof(System.Func<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(String)),
            typeof(String&),
            typeof(String)
            }, 
        null
        );
    // Method attributes
    method.Attributes = 
          System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.Public
        | System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.HideBySig;
    // Setting return type
    method.SetReturnType(typeof(Void));
    // Adding parameters
    method.SetParameters(
        typeof(String)
        );
    // Parameter value
    ParameterBuilder value =  method.DefineParameter(1, ParameterAttributes.None, "value");
    ILGenerator gen =  method.GetILGenerator();
    // Writing body
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldftn,method1);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj,ctor2);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldflda,field3);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call,method4);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    // finished
    return method;
}
```

The `<set_StudentName>b__0` method is the generated one for the lambda in the setter, which looks like this:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private string <set_StudentName>b__0()
{
    return this.StudentName;
}
```